# remove one of multiple query parameters in angular 6+

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

I get url like 
http://localhost:4444/categories/fashion?attributeValue=green&attributeValue=red 
how i could remove from query params attributeValue=red; In result i wanna get something like 
http://localhost:4444/categories/fashion?attributeValue=green

is that possible with router functionality?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can navigate to the current url with new query parameters.

```
this.router.navigate([], queryParams);
```